# Building a Virutal PC and Making it a DC

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, domain-controller

I am installing MS CRM Dynamics 4.0 on my Windows 2003 VM. However I get the error message -

action microsoft.crm.setup.common.analyzer+collectaction failed

One of the recommendations is to make the server a DC or add it to a domain. Now, my problem is that I am not sure how to make a Virtual PC as a DC and I cannot add it to my domain.

Question - How can I make my Windows 2003 Server as a DC?

Answer (score 1):

DCPROMO from the commandline.  But you'll need to have a one machine domain.  Why can't you add it to the existing domain?  Assuming there is one.

Everything should be the same within the VM as well as far as Windows is concerned

Answer (score 0):

If this CRM installation is purely for test purposes, LEAT's answer should be dandy - but do try to keep that DC isolated from your production network - for the admin's peace of mind.  However, if you want the users from your domain to use CRM, it's going to have to become a domain member.

I should say rather that you're going to want a very compelling reason to keep that server off the domain before you try to convince it to accept domain users without joining the domain itself.

It'd be kind of like taking the wheels off your car and attempting to find something else round and rubbery to replace them with.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is this server VM in, or going to be in production? If it's a permanent box, just add it as a member server to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Magic,

You shouldn't have to promote your server to be a DC - that doesn't sound like the right solution - more of a hack. Is the server part of the domain already?

I would recommend cleaning the new machine down, or starting again - then ensure the machine is added to the domain gracefully - THEN install CRM 4.0.

Good luck - post back the result of your work.

Mike